# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Увольнение произошло в связи с реорганизацией фирмы"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Увольнение произошло в связи с реорганизацией фирмы". Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна запятая, обстоятельственный оборот входит в основное содержание предложения, его нельзя обособить.

Comment: Спасибо большое